# configure DocumentRoot for cakephp 3 in openshift

Tags: openshift, cakephp-3.0

good I am new user in OpenShift, today I read the documentation, but it was not clear yet, how could I configure DocumentRoot. in my case I use cakephp 3 and for take my application into production I need to configure the DocumentRoot, this should be [webroot for production](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#production), I am very interested in OpenShift, I just need to get through this problem to carry my applications to the cloud. I read that OpenShift set [DocumentRoot](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/) but not if it applies to my case.

Comment: I did this just for test http://testcakephp3-fanaticcode.rhcloud.com/ , I have the same problem in two other applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's not possible to change `DocumentRoot` setting manually (just ask their support), then you could rename your apps `webroot` directory so that it conforms with OpenShifts automatic document root detection functionality:

> [...]
>
> The DocumentRoot is chosen by the cartridge control script logic depending on conditions in the following order:
>
> ```
> IF php/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=php/
> ELSE IF public/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public/
> ELSE IF public_html/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=public_html/
> ELSE IF web/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=web/
> ELSE IF www/ dir exists THEN DocumentRoot=www/
> ELSE DocumentRoot=/
> ```
>
> [...]

**https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-getting-started.html#set-document-root**

Maybe they'd even consider adding `webroot` to their script if you ask them.

### Changing your applications webroot directory

To change your applications `webroot` directory, you'll need to do two things

1. Change the directory name as needed (for example to `public`)
2. Adjust the `WWW_ROOT` constant in your apps `config/paths.php` file accordingly (for example `define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . 'public' . DS);`)

Comment: I have a question about this solution, if just add .htaccess for say that the DocumentRoot is webroot?

Comment: @Widrogo That won't work, the `DocumentRoot` setting can only be changed in the server- or virtual host config, see **http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#documentroot**.